# Как пользоваться хешами в go?(crypto)

Tags: golang, http, хеширование

Мне нужно 2 хеш функции, одна чтоб захешировать поролль, другая чтоб захешировать ключ сессии, обе должны выдавать 32 байтная хеш, подскажить как это сделать, не могу понять как пользоватсья пакетом крипто.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем 2 функции, если можно использовать одну, но с разной солью? `hash` отдаёт байтовый слайс с размером 32 используя [хэширующий алгоритм](https://medium.com/dtechlog/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-sha-256-9862302f942f) `SHA256`.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
)

func hash(value, salt string) [32]byte {
    var s = append([]byte(value), []byte(salt)...)
    return sha256.Sum256(s)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash("hello world", "salt-one"))
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash("hello world", "salt-two"))
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3vTIzCcBkWr)